# Cumulative sum and definite integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The definite integral $\int_0^6 x~dx$ is 18. The cumulative sum of the function over that domain is: $0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21$.

The values of definite integral and cumulative sum of this function are off by 3.

Is there a special function whose cumulative sum and its definite integral are always equal?

Comment: How it seems? The first one is 18 and the second 21.

Comment: You can achieve this with step functions, similar to the arguments in the [integral comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Comment: How about a constant function or the floor function?

Comment: Here's a better question: are there any *continuous* functions with this property?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the function $f(x):=[x]^-$ where $[x]^-$ is the floor $x$ because

$\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)=\sum_{k=0}^nk$

while

$\int_0^{n+1}f(x)dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_k^{k+1}k=\sum_{k=0}^n k$

Comment: By "inferior integer part", do you mean [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)? (I'd never seen this name for the function myself.)

Comment: @user170231 thank you